# C# - Convert int to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, integer

I am dealing with the following problem.
I have a bunch of int in 24h format without a colon. Something like this:

```
(HourMinute) meaning (Hour:Minute)
830          ->      08:30
1400         ->      14:00
245          ->      02:45
0            ->      00:00
2359         ->      23:59
etc.
```

From this I want to create a DateTime. Something like this:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
```

So how to fill the TimeSpan? Or, in general, how to create a DateTime with today's date and int's time (00 seconds)?

Comment: hours: `val / 100` minutes: `val % 100`

Comment: `var (hours, minutes) = Math.DivRem(value, 100);`

Comment: Actually, you may want to create a `TimeSpan` since there's no date information in there

Comment: Did you actually receive this data as an int? Or did you parse that int out of a string?

Comment: receive as an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to [divide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-) your integer by 100 to get hour part and calculate [reminder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) by 100 to get minutes part?

```
int i = 1430;
var hours = i / 100; // 14 because of integer division
var minutes = i % 100; // 30
```

Then

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
```

> I have a bunch of int in 24h format without a colon.

I have to mentioned that, this sentence is quite misleading. `int` (which is an alias for [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=net-7.0)) has *no* format. It has 32 bits which represent a number. All these *24 hour format* concept belongs to  [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0) type (aka *textual* representation). If you new about programming, it is important to understand what is a value of a type and a textual representation of a type.

EDIT:

As an alternative, you can use [`Math.DivRem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=net-7.0) method as
Dmitry mentioned in the comments which supports deconstructing declaration as [introduced with C# 7.0 version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/#deconstruction) like;

> Calculates the **quotient** of two numbers and **also returns the remainder** in an output parameter.

```
int i = 1430;
var (hours, minutes) = Math.DivRem(i, 100); 
var time = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: Now that you mention, it seems to be the solution because if you multiply this numbers to 100 you get the format in six digits.

Comment: Side note: or `var (hours, minutes) = Math.DivRem(i, 100);` then `var time = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);`